# como abrir eventos no fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

boa noite,

estou usando fullcalendar, mas não consigo abrir o evento, apenas apresentá-lo na agenda. Como arrumo isso no código?

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
            
          $('#calendario').fullCalendar({
              header: {
                    left: '',
                    center: 'prev, title, next',
                    right: ''
                },
                defaultDate: '2016-10-18',
                editable: false,
                eventLimit: true,
                eventSources: [{
                        events: [<?php echo $eventos;?>],
                   color: '#2089cf',    
                   textColor: '#fff' // an option!
                    }]
              
             
       }); 

         });
```

o php eventos é a variável que traz todos os eventos.

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é utilizar a configuração "[eventClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/)" e chamar uma popup ou navbar repassando as informações do evento.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

        console.log('Event: ' + calEvent.title);  // https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/
        console.log('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
        console.log('View: ' + view.name);

        // change the border color just for fun
        $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

        if (calEvent.url) {
            window.open(calEvent.url);
            return false;
        }
    }
});

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource',  
    [{
        id: 9,
        title: 'Evento Popup',
        start: '2017-01-04',
        end: '2017-01-04',
        color: 'pink',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
    }]
);
```